# last_login_at not working (null) w/ Authlogic Magic Columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, session, authlogic

I am using the [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic)gem for authentication and most of it seems to be working great. Authlogic [provides several columns](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example) that you can add to your Users table (for example) that it knows to fill in if they are present. i.e. login_count, current_login_ip, last_request_at and last_login_at.

All seem to be working fine with the exception of the last_login_at field which is null for each user.

Is there anything specific that could be causing this perhaps having to do with the user sessions, etc? I can post code if needed but wasn't sure what would relate to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that you are missing the `current_login_at` column, without it `last_login_at` will not work.

see: [here](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/session/magic_columns.rb)

```
if record.respond_to?(:current_login_at)
   record.last_login_at = record.current_login_at if record.respond_to?(:last_login_at)
   record.current_login_at = klass.default_timezone == :utc ? Time.now.utc : Time.now
end
```

Comment: Just for completeness: They have to be datetimes in your user_model. You can see an example here: https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example/blob/master/db/migrate/20081103171327_create_users.rb